# Which authorization policy is used if multiple policies are specified (e.g. middleware configuration, controller/action attribute,) in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization

I have the following configuration (default policy for all controllers):

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints
                .MapControllers()
                .RequireAuthorization();
        });
```

And then my controller overrides it with it's own Authorize attribute with another (non-default) policy

```
[Authorize("Full")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

Which policy is then used? I assume the one that controller and eventually action specifies, but perhaps all add up instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access `MyController` , it should match both policies :  the `DefaultPolicy` from `RequireAuthorization` and the custom `Full` policy . In addition , the `DefaultPolicy` could be updated by providing a policy to the `UseAuthorization` middleware :

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireClaim("claimName")
        .Build();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good, though the documentation seems to lack a bit :)

Comment: Same for action I assume? It adds up to be 3 different policies?